# Error on static Class

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = check.myValue("Example 1"); //This is the pattern I've to use, don't want to create an object (Is it possible to use it with static class)
        Console.WriteLine(c.result1);
        Console.WriteLine(c.result2);
    }
}

public static class check
{
    public static void myValue(string qr)
    {
        public string result1 = "My Name" + qr;
        public string result1 = "You're" + qr;
    }
}
```

[See here Online Example](http://rextester.com/ECURK91469) (Code is not working)

Every thing on main function I've to use exactly the same pattern because I'll use it in a lot of different classes and I don't want to create object each and every time by using non-static class.

**Please correct me if I'm wrong**

Comment: Method myValue returns `void`... How can`void` be converted into something ?

Comment: "Code is not working" is *never* enough information. *Always, always* include the error message, and what you've done to find out what that error means.

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot wrong with the syntax of that code, which @Sergey addresses in his answer.

You appear to want to return an instance of a class from a static method, and that class should contain two properties.

You can do that by creating the actual, nonstatic class containing the properties:

```
public class Check
{
    public string Result1 { get; set; }
    public string Result2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then return a new instance from the static method therein:

```
public static Check MyValue(string qr)
{
    var result = new Check();
    result.Result1 = "My Name" + qr;
    result.Result2 = "You're" + qr;
    return result;
}
```

However, you're saying in the comments in your code that you don't want to use an object.

In that case it appears you want to use static properties. That's generally not recommendable, but it would look like this:

```
public static class Check
{
    public static string Result1 { get; set; }
    public static string Result2 { get; set; }

    public static void MyValue(string qr)
    {
        Result1 = "My Name" + qr;
        Result2 = "You're" + qr;
    }   
}
```

Then you can read `Check.Result1` after calling the method `MyValue()`.

Comment: Sometimes life is unfair. The OP here actually needs a good C# book, not an answer that barely scratches the surface of the syntax. The question is actually both unclear and too broad. Yet it gives me five upvotes...

Comment: On the other hand your answer could really help OP to understand it better.

Comment: @Faizan if you're just starting out with C#, you don't want to write your own ORM. Look into Entity Framework, PetaPoco, Dapper or any of the other alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is totally wrong

1. `myValue` method returns `void`. You cannot assign `void` return value to variable.
2. You cannot have `public` modifiers for local variables.
3. You cannot have local variables with same name in same scope

If you want to return two values from method, then you should return object with two fields - custom class or tuple. You can also use out parameters, but I don't think it's your case

```
public static class Check
{
    public static Tuple<string, string> MyValue(string qr)
    {
        return Tuple.Create($"My Name {qr}", $"You're {qr}");
    }
}
```

With C# 7 it's a little bit better. You can write this method in one line and provide names for tuple properties

```
(string MyName, string YourName) MyValue(string qr) => ($"My Name {qr}", $"You're {qr}");
```

Usage

```
var result = Check.MyValue("Example 1");
Console.WriteLine(result.Item1); // result.MyName
Console.WriteLine(result.Item2); // result.YourName
```

You can practice with creating custom class with nicely named properties instead of using tuples.

Comment: Also you can't declare two variables with the same name in the same scope (`result1`).

Comment: Can I also pass Dictionary in it?

Comment: @FaizanRupani yes, you can, but dictionary doesn't give you hint on which values it have. You can use simple `List<string>` if you want just return couple of unnamed values